# Compile files using Notepad++ and Intel Fortran Compiler

Tags: fortran, notepad++

I'm newbie, using Notepad++, but I'm programming with Fortran Intel Compiler. I would like to compile and run my Fortran scripts using, directly, Notepad++. Could anyone help me to say me, what I need to do in order to configure Notepad++ to compile in Fortran? I know that I can compile some programs, if I have in Notepad++ the plug-in NppExec that I have it. Regards.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What exactly is your question? NppExec's documentation has a "basic usage" topic that's pretty clear, and has examples of using both the `Console` and `Execute...` forms of compiling.

Comment: @KenWhite - Although I cannot help with the N++ part, (and I don't feel like installing it now just for this; I'm lazy) I find the question perfectly clear. He is asking how to configure N++ for compiling/linking and executing fortran files. Seriously, are we so "intelligent" that every question needs to have a question mark following it to be understood as such. I know parsers more flexible than that.

Comment: @ldigas: There is not a question here. Would it help if I copied and pasted the instructions from the **help file** that comes with the plugin? I pointed the poster to the appropriate location, and did **not** downvote or vote to close. Perhaps I should be more clear: 'click the "Plugins" menu, then the "NppExec", and from it's menu click "Help/Manual", open the "Basic usage" topic, and then read the "Console" and "Execute..." instructions'?

Comment: @KenWhite - Well, try putting that down as an answer to see if it helps, instead of arguing here with me. If those help files were so clear there wouldn't be a whole bunch of questions on the 'net asking how to set it up (and nearly every editor in existance has a hundred of those).

Comment: @ldigas, I didn't post it as an answer because there's no question here - that was my whole point. :)

Comment: @KenWhite - <sigh> suit yourself ...

Comment: You seem to have found the correct plugin, so (1) did you try something? and if so, (2) what specific problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do this:

Click the 'Run' button and then 'Run...' again. Now write the command line script that runs the file, in my case it is:

```
gfortran "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" -o "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH).exe"
```

And save the command.  Note, the word `FULL_CURRENT_PATH` refers to the fully qualified path to the current document.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to use notepad++ for writing Fortran programs. I suggest you to use Codeblocks with Fortran plugin (see here: http://darmar.vgtu.lt/). With this, you can edit/compile/debug any mixed Fortran/C++ program in windows and Linux.

Comment: I see no need for that; if he's got Intel's compiler he's got the VS shell integration as well.

Comment: Yes, but Codeblocks with Fortran plugin supports Fortran03-08 standard with lots of capabilities that makes Fortran coding much easier. I tried VS and it's no way near Codeblocks for Fortran.

Comment: I wouldn't go that far; admittedly I haven't used Codeblocks (for a long time), but VS is a great IDE. It has excellent project management, and its debugger and Intel's integrated feature set is superb. I would say it is probably a matter of personal preference and taste.

Comment: @HosseinTalebi. Thanks! You're right! I'm using Code::Blocks with fortran. I tried this software with the gfortran in Linux and it worked very well.